# MySQL - Select SUM from more than one table

Tags: mysql

Anyone can help with this short mysql query:

```
SELECT 
   mr.matcode, 
   IFNULL(SUM(mr.mr_qty),0) AS total_mr_qty, 
   IFNULL(SUM(mb.out_qty), 0) AS out_qty
FROM mr 
   INNER JOIN material m 
     ON mr.matcode = m.matcode 
   INNER JOIN job_order jo 
     ON mr.jo_no = jo.jo_no  
   LEFT OUTER JOIN min_out_body mb 
     ON mr.jo_no = mb.jo_no 
     AND mr.mr_no = mb.mr_no 
     AND mr.matcode = mb.matcode 
   WHERE m.matcode >= '600NH04R0003220' 
     AND m.matcode <= '600NH04R0003220' 
     AND UCASE(jo.status) NOT LIKE 'C%' 
   GROUP BY mr.matcode, mb.matcode
```

**mr table as below:**

```
mr_no     matcode            mr_qty         jo_no
----------------------------------------------------------
MR001     600NH04R0003220    2800           S6914-S01
MR002     600NH04R0003220    1800           S6915-S01
```

**job_order table as below:**

```
jo_no           status
-------------------------
S6914-S01       RELEASED
S6915-S01       RELEASED
```

**min_out_table table as below:**

```
doc_no     item_no     matcode             out_qty        jo_no      mr_no
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A001       001         600NH04R0003220     1700           S6914-S01  MR001
A001       002         600NH04R0003220     1000           S6914-S01  MR001
A002       001         600NH04R0003220     1700           S6915-S01  MR002
```

**material table as below:**

```
matcode             descr                       u_measure
-------------------------------------------------------------------
600NH04R0003220     Dummy Description Here      KG
```

The result that i am trying to get is :

```
matcode            total_mr_qty             out_qty       
---------------------------------------------------------
600NH04R0003220    4600                     4400
```

However using the above query, the result is:

```
matcode            total_mr_qty             out_qty
-------------------------------------------------------------
600NH04R0003220    7400                     4400
```

The Column **mr_qty** result will be  doubled, which is incorrect.

can someone tell me what's wrong with above query?

**UPDATE 1**: Add material table

**UPDATE 2** : Add test fiddle at [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWn3WVD9dHe135rPXV7iLb/0)

Comment: Contents and structure of "material" table please? 5 tables are referenced in sql but 4 are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1:**

```
 AND mr.mr_no = mb.mr_no
```

will generate error as per your table structure / data. And this you had clarified in your fiddle. So no issue.

**Point 2:**

```
   LEFT OUTER JOIN min_out_body mb
```

will join for all of mb wherein there are two entries for same jo_no 'S6914-S01'. This will take rows from other table two times.

**Point 3:**

```
   ...
   INNER JOIN job_order jo 
     ON mr.jo_no = jo.jo_no  
   LEFT OUTER JOIN min_out_body mb 
     ON mr.jo_no = mb.jo_no 
   ...
```

**The correction:**

```
   left outer JOIN (select doc_no, item_no, matcode, sum(out_qty) out_qty, jo_no from min_out_body group by jo_no)  mb
```

This will make the mb to have unique (jo_no) rows

**One doubt:**

The output may be jo_no based too. Please check.

Comment: i have make a correction to the table **min_out_body** and **mr** by adding **mr_no** to them and create a fiddle. Tried your correction but it game an error.

Comment: I had edited my reply too - You shall skip Point 1. And the rest would explain what you should do to get your required result. Also take care if you want jo_no also in the output columns in that case the output will have more rows (per jo_no also).

Comment: tried to update fiddle with your correction, however it generate an error, am i missing something here? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWn3WVD9dHe135rPXV7iLb/1

Comment: You miss the ON condition1 and condition2 for the third JOIN. Once you check this, please mark as choosen answer and upvote the same.